# Finding the full network connected with a node in neo4j

Tags: graph, neo4j, tree, cypher, py2neo

Suppose I have a neo4j graph with 3 different kind of nodes (say `type A`, `type B`, `type C`).

There are :

- 5 nodes of `type A`
- 40 nodes of `type B`
- 200 nodes of `type C`

Each node of `type A` are connecting to one or more of `type B` (`(A -> B)`) and each node of `type B`  are connecting to one or more of `type C` (`(B -> C)`).

One node of type B can be shared by more than one type A nodes `(A1 -> B1, A2 -> B1)` and one node of type C can be shared by more than one type B nodes `(B1 -> C1, B2 -> C1)`.

No node of `type A` connects with any node of `type C`. And the relationships are directional as described above.

For a given node of `type A`, can I find out all the nodes in the connected network, i.e., the **entire tree emerging from that node**, and not just the immediately connected nodes?

So basically I am looking for a `py2neo` function or cypher query that can give me a full tree or full network emerging from a given node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this query respond to your needs ?

```
MATCH p=(a:A)-->(b:B)-->(c:C)
WHERE a.id = 'your id' // your condition to find your specific A node
RETURN p
```